# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".9284912"

Tags: python, tkinter

Well,I want to use the create_image in the b class,but it didn't work,and when I closing the python 3 program,it showed an error as :_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".51752240"

```
import tkinter
class GUI:
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    def __init__(self):

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.root, width=1024, height=960, bg="White")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.t=tkinter.PhotoImage(file='hj.jpg')
        # self.canvas.create_image(100,100,image=self.t)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def draw(self,x,y):
        self.canvas.create_image(x,y,image=self.t)
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        G=GUI()
        G.draw(100,200)
b()
```

Thanks to anyone who can reply and help on this!!

Comment: I don't think `PhotoImage` supports JPG's does it?  Also, `self.root` isn't defined.  Either change to `root` everywhere, or change `root=tkinter.Tk()` to `self.root=tkinter.Tk()`

Comment: Thanks a lot,I try again,it doesn't support JPG.Maybe I changed its extension somewhere.But I think the code with root is defined as self.root.

Answer (score 2):

Only the first line of `b.__init__()` gets executed when you initially run this program; that function contains an infinite loop in the form of `self.root.mainloop()`.  Once you close the window, the mainloop finally exits, and execution continues to `G.draw()` - which fails, because the canvas you're trying to draw on no longer exists.  You need to move the mainloop() call to a later point in the code - perhaps either `b.__init__()`, or the top level at the very end of the file.